# Implementing an array of linked lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers, graph, structure

Working with graphs right now, and pretty stuck on creating an array of linked lists (adjacency list), tried few variations, but got this error:

> [Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'node*')

```
class node {
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }   
};

void SS_in(){
    int nver;
    node **listik;
    cout << "vvedite kolvo vershin";
    cin >> nver;
    for (int i=0; i<nver;i++){
        cout << "V" << i << ": ";
        cin >> listik[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to be able to read in a `node *`?

Comment: You are trying to read into a pointer. It would be strange to expect the user to type in a memory address!

Comment: what is `node **listik;` supossed to be? use `std::vector<node*>` for a dynamically sized array of pointers and `std::vector<std::vector<node>>` for a 2d array. Btw in your code you never create a single `node`. All you have is pointers

Comment: I recommend sitting down with pen and paper and drawing out how you want the array of linked lists to be represented in memory.

Comment: well pointers are my weak point. I haven't read about vectors yet, would like to make it using pointers (to become better in them instead of mixing in vectors). Basically cin>>listik[i] means I'm trying to type in adress, yes? But I need to use ** pointer, because I have an array of lists, right?

Comment: Hold off on doing anything tricky with pointers right now and make sure you understand dynamic allocation. Once you have that figured out you'll be in a better place to tackle linking objects together with pointers.

Comment: I see it like that https://ibb.co/FDK3nQn

Comment: the most important step in becoming better with pointers is knowing how to avoid them. Use the right tool for the right job. It is a bit sad, but finding a good job for a raw pointer is really difficult nowadays

Comment: If this is an exercise to learn, then more power to you, but if you just want to implement without having to worry about the guts, consider using the STL `array` (or `vector` for dynamic sizing) and `forward_list` (for a singly-linked list) or `list` (for a doubly-linked list).

Comment: @Stanislav on the drawing that's pretty close to what you want, but it will be a bit more descriptive id you include how the linked lists are linked together. That little bit, obtaining and maintaining valid linking, is probably going to take you more work to get right in the code than anything else in the program.

Answer (score 1):

I will intervene only on the compilation error that you have and not on your need to build a linked list because your request is not clear.
You must overload the operator `>>` for your class before you can use it:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class node {
public :
    int data;
    node* next;

    node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }   

    friend istream & operator >> (istream &in,  node &myNode); 
};

istream & operator >> (istream &in,  node &myNode) 
{ 
    cout << "Enter node data :"<< endl;
    in >> myNode.data; 

    return in; 
} 

int main()
{
    node myNode(2);
    cin >> myNode;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only node and graph (listik) are defined.

On this stage the error could be fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node {
public:
  int data;
  node* next;
  node (int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
};

void SS_in () {
  int nver;
  std::cout << "vvedite kolvo vershin";
  std::cin >> nver;

  node** listik = new node * [nver];

  int tempData;
  for (int i = 0; i < nver; i++) {
    cout << "V" << i << ": ";
    cin >> tempData;
    listik[i] = new node(tempData);
  }
}

void main () {
  SS_in ();
}
```

Class adjacencyList (linked list) should be added.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
node **listik;
...
...
    cin >> listik[i];
```

is wrong in two ways.

1) `listik` is uninitialized and consequently so is `listik[i]`. In other words - you are trying to read into memory that your program (most likely) doesn't own.

2) Since `listik` is a "pointer to pointer to node", `listik[i]` is a "pointer to node". Asking a user to type in a pointer value is meaningless and - lucky you - you got a compile error telling you that.

Now for your real question:

> ... creating an array of linked lists ...

Remember that a linked list start with a head element which is a "pointer to node". So to get an array of linked lists, you need an array of "pointer to node".

For instance:

```
node* arr_of_lists[20];
```

will be an array with 20 "pointer to node". And therefore something you can use as an array of 20 linked list.

Or in a more c++ like style:

```
std::array<node*, 20> arr_of_lists;
```

Or with dynamic allocation so that you can control the array size at runtime:

```
node** arr_of_lists = new node*[desired_size];
```

When reading data from the user, you'll need two informations:

1) The data value for the node to be added

2) Which of the (e.g. 20) linked lists to add the node to.

Like:

```
cin >> data;
cin >> list_index;

// Skipping error checks here... but must be added to the real code

// You need a function like this to creat an new node holding
// data and insert the new node to the linked list at index "list_index"
list_insert(arr_of_lists, list_index, data);
```